# Увеличение производительности видеоизображения через камеру. OpenCV, Tensorflowm, Python

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow

Всем доброго времени суток! Недавно решил сделать проект по распознаванию объектов через видеокамеру. Все написал, поисправлял ошибки и настроил систему и по итогу все заработало. Но при отображении видео, оно немного тормозит и иногда фризит, если кто знает как можно оптимизировать весь процесс или добавить что-нибудь в код для увеличение производительности ,буду благодарен:3
Код:

```
import os
from imageai.Detection import ObjectDetection
import cv2 as vc
import time


os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'

camera = vc.VideoCapture(0)

detector = ObjectDetection()
detector.setModelTypeAsYOLOv3()
detector.setModelPath("yolo.h5")
detector.loadModel()

finish = 0

array_detection = []

while camera.isOpened():
        ret, frame = camera.read()
        start = time.time()
        if start-finish > 1.2:
            _, array_detection = detector.detectObjectsFromImage(input_image=frame, input_type="array", output_type="array")
            finish = time.time()

        for obj in array_detection:
            coord = obj['box_points']
            vc.rectangle(frame, (coord[0], coord[1]), (coord[2], coord[3]), (0, 0, 255))
            vc.putText(frame, obj['name'], (coord[0], coord[1] - 6), vc.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, 1.0, (255, 0, 0), 1)
        vc.imshow('Vision', frame)
        if  vc.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q') or ret == False:
            break

camera.release()
vc.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Может попробовать детект запускать отдельным тредом/потоком, чтобы он не мешал отображению видео. Или может слишком много объектов на видео находится и отрисовывается, как-то их кол-во ограничить?

Comment: @CrazyElf На видео (при подключении камеры к компьютеру) может находиться неограниченное количество объектов, но в этом так таковой проблемы скорее всего нет (не уверен), так как когда я фокусировал камеру только на себя и камера в своем диапозоне видела только меня, видеопоток был заторможен и так же фризил (примерно 2с работы и 5с фриза). Попробую что вы посоветовали, может получиться. Хотя недавно читал статью одну и там человек делал эксперимент, где он запускал такую же программу (примерно такой же код) с потоками и без и результаты примерно одинаковы. Ну попробую, заранее спасибо

Comment: Ну вы сделайте какое-нибудь логирование или вывод в консоль и посмотрите - сколько времени детектирование длится, и сколько отрисовка. Чтобы понимать - что вообще тормозит, собственно

Comment: Хорошо, сейчас попробую

Comment: Если окажется, что само детектирование тормозит, то, собственно, у вас выбор небогатый будет. Даже если сделаете отдельный поток правильным образом - ну, фризов не будет, зато само детектирование будет отставать на несколько секунд от видео. Фиг знает как лучше так или эдак.